# HTML form action is prepending value instead of appending value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following form. I would like to have the url be: http://myapp/library/#/iframe?title=Search&url=http:%2F%2Fencore.scranton.edu%2Fiii%2Fencore%2Fsearch%2F?lang=eng&target=Einstein

```
<form action="#/iframe?title=Search&url=http://encore.scranton.edu/iii/encore/search/" id="form" method="get" name="form" >
  <input name="target" type="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="search-input">
</form>
```

But instead its prepending: http://myapp/library/?target=Einstein#/iframe?title=Search&url=http:%2F%2Fencore.scranton.edu%2Fiii%2Fencore%2Fsearch%2F?lang=eng

**Angular code:**

iframe/templates/index.html

```
<div ui-view class="container">
....
        <div class="animated fadeIn iframe">
            <iframe src="{{ url }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

iframe/controller.js

```
        //
        //  Routes
        //
      .state('iframe', {
        url         : '/iframe?title&url',
        templateUrl : 'modules/Iframe/templates/index.html',
        controller  : 'IframeController'
      })
    }]);
```

Comment: what is your js code? Also - side point is encore.scranton.edu your domain? Have you checked for CSRF issues?

Comment: the javascript is rather complicated. I'm just curious why its prepending the value and not appending?

Comment: BTW I am using Angular... iframe is an angular module that takes the url and displays it in an iframe in an angular template.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the JS, I might be dancing in the dark, but did you try something like this?

Assuming no frameworks

```
var myform = document.getElementById("form");
var action = myform.getAttribute("action"); 
//reset the entire attribute
myform.setAttribute(action+"value_i_want_appended");
```

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to do this. I just don't understand why its prepending the target value and not appending. If I throw in a regular url it appends but with the pound sign it prepends... why?

Comment: good question. Will have to look that up, clearly the JS engine feels like this is the proper way to do it, based on it looking like an anchor. Does this occur on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<form action="http://encore.scranton.edu/iii/encore/search/?title=Search" id="form" method="get" name="form" >
    <input name="target" type="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="search-input" />
    <input name="title" type="hidden" value="Search" />
</form>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hg1r3awa/)

Comment: Yes that works, but I have a custom iframe code that I need to use. I'm just curious why its prepending the value and not appending?

Comment: I don't understand what is _custom iframe code_, if you want to load it into iframe then just use form `target` attribute, if you have some specific JS library (I do not know any like that and I do not see any in your question tags/description) which handles this `action` attribute then the library just fails. Otherwise it tries to build the relative path based on your current URL, see [form action description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var currentURL = $("#form").prop('action');
var newAction = 'http://myapp/library/' + currentURL + '&target=Einstein';
$("#form").prop('action', newAction);
```